# How to correctly work with bytes reading in JavaScript? How to correctly select position

Tags: javascript, hex

I need to read some decimal values from HEX.

For example, I have 2-tariffs electicity metering and with LoRa IOT device I read and send 2 integer values 33780 and 6687 (kilowatts) to my server.

They are encoded in this HEX message on 4th to 6th position and 8th to 10th position. With JavaScript, I need to convert back to a integer values.

80 ff 02 **00 83 f4** 03 **00 1a 1f** fe f1

**00 83 f4** = 33780

**00 4a 4f** = 6687

So I have some JavaScript example, but I cannot fit correct positions for reading. Problem is in line 2 and 3 of course.

```js
function Decoder(bytes) {
  var T2 = bytes[1]<<24>>16 | bytes[0];
  var T1 = bytes[4]<<6 | bytes[3];

  return {
    vysoky_tarif: T2,
    nizky_tarif: T1
    
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please clarify, what Type your input is. Bytes are numbers, they are neither Decimal nor Hex. Their string-representation may be,

Comment: 33780 and 6687 are integers (without decimal point)

Comment: wrong end, that's the output. I asked about what type comes in. What type is `bytes` in `function Decoder(bytes)`?

Comment: device read values 33780 and 6687 (this are electrical values - kilowatts on electricity meter), code it with another informations in into message 80 ff 02 00 83 f4 03 00 1a 1f fe f1. Server receive this message and I must extract target values. There are on 4th to 6th positions and 8th to 10th positions.

Comment: OK, how do you *"code it with another informations in into message"*? is `"80 ff 02 00 83 f4 03 00 1a 1f fe f1"` literally the string that the server recieves and needs to parse? or do you send a `ByteArray` containing these bytes?

Comment: Yes, "80 ff 02 00 83 f4 03 00 1a 1f fe f1" is string that server recives and need to parse data on bytes 4 - 6 and 8 - 10. I was edited topic to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, "80 ff 02 00 83 f4 03 00 1a 1f fe f1" is string that server recives and need to parse data on bytes 4 - 6 and 8 - 10.

The differrence between your string and the bytes is the same like between a picture and you. Doesn't make much sense to talk to a picture of you.

So first we have to parse this string into numbers that we can deal with.
Then we need to get the numbers you're looking for.

imo. 24bit numbers are rather rare, for 8, 16 and 32bit values you could use a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) to get/set the values right on the Array, for 24 bit we need to get the bytes and build the integers manually.

```js
// your input, a string
var text = "80 ff 02 00 83 f4 03 00 1a 1f fe f1";

// parsed and converted into an Array of Bytes.
var bytes = new Uint8Array(text.split(" ").map(v => parseInt(v, 16)));

// a utility to read int24 from the array
function getInt24(bytes, index) {
  return (bytes[index] << 24 | bytes[index + 1] << 16 | bytes[index + 2]<<8) >> 8;
}

// 1st byte is at index 0
var v1 = getInt24(bytes, 3);
var v2 = getInt24(bytes, 7);

console.log(v1, v2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: it works without cleaning text and parsing to new Unit8Array.

Answer (score 0):

This is final working code:

```
function Decoder(bytes) {

// a utility to read int24 from the array
function getInt24(bytes, index) { return (bytes[index] << 24 | bytes[index + 1] << 16 | bytes[index + 2]<<8) >> 8;
}

// 1st byte is at index 0
var v1 = getInt24(bytes, 3);
var v2 = getInt24(bytes, 7);


return {
    vysoky_tarif: v1,
    nizky_tarif: v2
       }
}
```